# Unity/Android/iOS Pop-up windows and lock rest of screen

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I am totally newbie in Unity.
I have some pop-up windows in my 2d project. I want "block" rest of screen if pop up window is active.
How i can achive this?
I am working with android.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome new user, it's actually pretty simple.

if you are used to programming ios or android, it's different, you simply do it "manually".

All you do is ...

- in your UI
- make a new panel which is full screen, name it "gray cover" or such
- make it 90% alpha and black
- in fact simply put your popups on top of that
- when you want one of your popups to appear, just turn on the gray cover and whichever popup/message you want

Enjoy